# Scanning sum() of Decimal type with Go, sqlx, ClickHouse

Tags: go, clickhouse, sqlx, clickhouse-go

I have a "Duration" field of type Decimal(38, 3) in a ClickHouse table.

From my Golang service I'm sending a query to get the SUM() of it but I just can't scan the result back. I tried using int, uint, float, **sql.NullFloat64**, a struct type, scanning row by row, the whole struct, arrays, structs with arrays, using sqlx.Query, sqlx.Select and nothing worked.

```golang
rows, _ := s.db.Query("SELECT sum(Duration) AS duration FROM mytable")
for rows.Next() {
    var count sql.NullFloat64
    log.Println(rows.Scan(&count))
    log.Printf("count: %v\n", count)
}
```

I always get back this kind of errors:
`sql: Scan error on column index 0, name "duration": converting driver.Value type []uint8 ("\x04!\xdf\xdc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00") to a float64: invalid syntax`

While checking some of the rows info I get the following:

```
log.Printf("db type name: %v\n", t.DatabaseTypeName())
log.Printf("db scan type: %v\n", t.ScanType())
>>>
db type name: Decimal(38, 3)
db scan type: []uint8
```

For other SELECT statements of Decimal types without aggregation functions I used float32/64 but this one just refuses to work.

Running the query directly in the console I get a single value as expected: 3702.5

Any ideas?

--- UPDATE 1 ---

I manage to scan it into a byte array but I don't know how to transform it into the number shown in the client: 3708199.5

```golang
count := []byte{}
rows.Scan(&count)
log.Printf("count: %v\n", count)
>>>
count: [76 162 6 221 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: which version clickhouse-go driver do you use?
did you try https://github.com/clickhouse/clickhouse-go/tree/v2 ?

Comment: I fixed it by casting the result with toUInt64(sum...)
How silly of me, I'm using 1.5.1, I'll update to v2 right away.

Answer (score 1):

After migration from v1 to v2 of the library, the `sum()` returns now an string, but it still fails because the destination is a float, so I cast the value to a known type to fix it.

```
rows, _ := s.db.Query("SELECT toDecimal64(sum(Duration), 2) AS duration FROM mytable")
```